# Как вывести результат функции на экран через нажатие кнопки (модуль Tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x

Столкнулся с проблемой. Есть функция

```
def get_one(name, descr)
 return print(f'{name}:{descr}')
get_one('Aim of life', 'Drama')
```

Нужно вывести результат её работы на экран в окошко при нажатии кнопки. И простой передачей функции и через get у меня не вышло. Может, кто-то сможет подсказать решение проблемы

```
root = Tk()
def one_click():
    get_one()
    
root.title('Kino Afisha')
root.geometry('500x650')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
one = get_all_films()
btn = Button(root, text="Не нажимать!", command=one_click)  

btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: так а куда в хотите вывести?

Comment: либо в отдельное окошко через messagebox, либо в область окна на Canvas